# Docker copy command to copy a jar file from target folder

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a maven project that outputs a jar file into the target folder. What relative path can i use in the copy command in the Dockerfile to access the jar from within the target folder.

Answer (score 3):

The Docker `COPY`command runs relative to the Dockerfile location.

So if you have a the Dockerfile at the root of your project; same as the target folder; then simpley you can use:

`docker build .` and use `COPY target/myapp.jar /opt/my_app/lib`

If on the other hand you have a project structure such:

- /docker/Dockerfile
- /src
- /target/myapp.jar

Then you will need to move to the root of the project and run:

`docker build -f docker/Dockerfile .`

(Ps you can also navigate to the docker dir and run `docker build -f Dockerfile ..`)

---

OS: **macOS Catalina 10.15.5**

Docker: **19.03.8**

Answer (score 0):

if the Dockerfile lives in directory A and you directory sturcture is

directory C is inside directory B which is inside directory A

directory C contains your JAR

```
COPY /b/c/yourfile.JAR /where/to/copy/it/inside/container
```

if you do not want to COPY the JAR into your container BUT still want to access the JAR file then you might consider creating a VOLUME