# My Dockerfile isn't able to acces the jar file

Tags: java, docker, microservices

I'm really a newbie in Java and Docker, so please go easy on me.
I'm trying to build two microservices that communicate and running them into the `docker compose`, but it returns this error:

> Unable to access jar file
>   hello-consumer-microservice-message-1.0-snapshot.jar.

Here's my dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine-jdk:base
WORKDIR ./files
EXPOSE 8081
CMD ["java", "-jar", "hello-consumer-microservice-message-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

I've tried alternating the `CMD` with `ENTRYPOINT`, but achieved no success, so, could anyone help me ?

P.S: If you have any good reads on these subjects, you can link them in the answers too, I really want to improve my skills !

Comment: where is the .jar located?

Comment: See the `COPY` instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36360324/docker-copy-command-to-copy-a-jar-file-from-target-folder

Comment: The .jar is in a folder called files that's in the folder where the Dockerfiles are, so my WORKDIR is (place where the docker files are)/files (place with the .jar).

Comment: Thanks Josue, I'll take a look and try it!

Comment: You didn't `COPY` jar file into docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `COPY` or `ADD` to include files in an image - for more details see: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/dockerfile-copy-vs-add-key-differences-and-best-practices-9570c4592e9e

In your case you can simply add the line `ADD hello-consumer-microservice-message-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar`

and then change your `CMD` to:

`CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]`

I've `ADD`ed the jar with the name `app.jar`for better readability.

So your final Dockerfile will look like this:

```
FROM alpine-jdk:base
WORKDIR ./files
EXPOSE 8081
ADD hello-consumer-microservice-message-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```